# Is having an 'OR' in an INNER JOIN condition a bad idea?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, inner-join

In trying to improve the speed of an immensely slow query (several *minutes* on two tables with only ~50,000 rows each, on SQL Server 2008 if it matters), I narrowed down the problem to an `OR` in my inner join, as in:

```
SELECT mt.ID, mt.ParentID, ot.MasterID
  FROM dbo.MainTable AS mt
  INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS ot ON ot.ParentID = mt.ID
                                  OR ot.ID = mt.ParentID
```

I changed this to (what I hope is) an equivalent pair of left joins, shown here:

```
SELECT mt.ID, mt.ParentID,
   CASE WHEN ot1.MasterID IS NOT NULL THEN
      ot1.MasterID ELSE
      ot2.MasterID END AS MasterID
  FROM dbo.MainTable AS mt
  LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS ot1 ON ot1.ParentID = mt.ID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS ot2 ON ot2.ID = mt.ParentID
  WHERE ot1.MasterID IS NOT NULL OR ot2.MasterID IS NOT NULL
```

.. and the query now runs in about a second!

Is it generally a bad idea to put an `OR` in a join condition?  Or am I just unlucky somehow in the layout of my tables?

Comment: Show us the execution plan instead of your query.

Comment: seems like an odd relationship

Comment: @Blindy: good idea.  It turns out the execution plans show just what Quassnoi mentions below: the first query results in nested loops, while the second is done with a hash join.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

This kind of `JOIN` is not optimizable to a `HASH JOIN` or a `MERGE JOIN`.

It can be expressed as a concatenation of two resultsets:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    maintable m
JOIN    othertable o
ON      o.parentId = m.id
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    maintable m
JOIN    othertable o
ON      o.id = m.parentId
```

, each of them being an equijoin, however, `SQL Server`'s optimizer is not smart enough to see it in the query you wrote (though they are logically equivalent).

Comment: this makes sense, thank you.  I'm still not sure if there is something peculiar about my query, or if I should just avoid joins of the `ON w=x OR y=z` pattern entirely?

Comment: @ladenedge: these joins will be performed using a table scan in a nested loop. This is slow if your tables are large.

Comment: just to be clear, when you say "these joins," you mean all joins of the form `ON w=x OR y=z`?  (Thanks for your patience!)

Comment: @ladenedge: there may be additional conditions which could help `SQL Server` understand that a concatenation would be needed. Say, the query `SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE parentId = 1 OR id = 2` will use a concatenation if both fields are indexed so theoretically there is nothing that would prevent doing the same thing in a loop. Whether `SQL Server` will build this plan actually or not, depends on very many factors, but I've never seen it built in real life.

Comment: Also note that if you know they are disjoint sets, union ALL can improve performance significantly by avoiding merging the result sets.

Comment: @Quassnoi any idea if the above query would be more performant on Oracle Database as well?

Comment: @hipokito: because Oracle is not that smart either?

Answer (score 11):

I use following code for get different result from condition 
That worked for me.

---

```
Select A.column, B.column
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN
TABLE2 B
ON A.Id = (case when (your condition) then b.Id else (something) END)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use UNION ALL instead

```sql
SELECT mt.ID, mt.ParentID, ot.MasterID
FROM dbo.MainTable AS mt
UNION ALL
SELECT mt.ID, mt.ParentID, ot.MasterID
FROM dbo.OtherTable AS ot
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` will give you duplicates compared to the `JOIN` with an `OR` condition.

Comment: For that UNION will be right. For more details read the following link [union-instead-of-or](http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/using-union-instead-of-or)

Comment: yes but in your example you written it with `union all` which is not correct as the article you link to also describes.