# SQL Server 2005 strange performance boost of query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is having an 'OR' in an INNER JOIN condition a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea)

Look at this example of tables (not real):

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR(64),
    author VARCHAR(64),
    user_id BIGINT
)

CREATE TABLE User
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    mail VARCHAR(64)
)
```

Imagine, this tables have indexes for all
columns you would like to search...

This is my first query:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (o.product in ('aaa','bbb'))
       OR (o.author in ('user1','user2')) 
       OR (u.mail in ('a@a.com','b@b.com'))
```

First is VERY-VERY-VERY slow...

**100M Orders x 100M Users => 10 mins**

This is my second query:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (o.product in ('aaa','bbb'))
       OR (o.author in ('user1','user2')) 
    UNION 
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (u.mail in ('a@a.com','b@b.com'))
```

Second is VERY slow...

**100M Orders x 100M Users => 4 mins**

This is my third query:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (o.product in ('aaa','bbb'))
    UNION 
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (o.author in ('user1','user2')) 
    UNION 
   SELECT *
     FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN user u
       ON o.user_id = u.id
    WHERE (u.mail in ('a@a.com','b@b.com'))
```

Third query is really FAST!!!

**100M Orders x 100M Users => 0.1 sec**

Why SQL Server 2005 can't do this automatically?

**UPD**: Changed UNION ALL to UNION

**UPD2**:

> first and second query: 90% of plan is "Matching Hash"
>
> third query:            88% of plan is "Clustered index search".

Comment: Did you look at the execution plans for each of your queries to see if you find a clue there?

Comment: You need to post the exec plans.

Comment: 1 and 2: 90% of plan is "Matching Hash" 3: 88% of plan is "Clustered index search"...

Comment: Are you **sure** it's `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`?  If it is  you need to update the Q as well.

Comment: @JNK the query has `UNION ALL`

Comment: @Magnus - I posted an answer around that and he commented: `My mistake. There should be UNION insted of UNION ALL.`