# SQL query efficiency - impact of UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have recently written a stored procedure which has this part

```
select T.Id from Teams T
inner join 
(
    select SG.Team1Id, SG.Team2Id from SG
    union all
    select SP.Team1Id, SP.Team2Id from SP
) G
on T.Id in (G.Team1Id, G.Team2Id)
```

I am doubtful about this query efficiency

Will this query fetch all the records from `SG` and `SP` in the subquery and then will apply join condition? If yes, then I think this is not efficient

or

Sql server is smart enough to only fetch the rows from both the tables that matches the criteria of join?

Comment: Post the query plan so we can understand how the engine will execute this query.

Comment: `on T.Id in (G.Team1Id, G.Team2Id)` means you will always get a nested loops join. It is `T.Id = G.Team1Id or T.Id = G.Team2Id`. See [Is having an 'OR' in an INNER JOIN condition a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea/5901901#5901901)

Answer (score 2):

The `UNION ALL` in the derived table will likely be **more** efficient than the alternative formulation of

```
SELECT T.Id
FROM   Teams T
       INNER JOIN SG
         ON T.Id IN ( SG.Team1Id, SG.Team2Id )
UNION ALL
SELECT T.Id
FROM   Teams T
       INNER JOIN SP
         ON T.Id IN ( SP.Team1Id, SP.Team2Id )
```

Because the version in your question will only need one pass through `Teams`. If the tables `SP` and `SG` have constraints such that `Team1Id` cannot be the same as `Team2Id` and the individual columns are indexed then the following could perform better (for some data distributions, especially if `Teams` is relatively large compared to the other tables involved )

```
SELECT T.Id
FROM   Teams T
       INNER JOIN (SELECT SG.Team1Id
                   FROM   SG
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT SG.Team2Id
                   FROM   SG
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT SP.Team1Id
                   FROM   SP
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT SP.Team2Id
                   FROM   SP) G(TeamId)
         ON T.Id = G.TeamId
```

Comment: Also, the optimizer can go from 2 to one but not from one to two. This is an unfortunate limitation as of 2012.