# SQL Server join on whichever column has value populated

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have two tables each with the following id columns:

```
Ticker
SEDOL,
ISIN
```

Each row has one or more of these columns populated with a value. I would like to join on whichever column has a value. Does anyone know how to join this way? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share more information of your table and what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

`Ticker`, `SEDOL` and `ISIN` are all different formats so I assume you need

```
SELECT *
FROM   T1
       JOIN T2
         ON T1.Ticker = T2.Ticker
             OR T1.SEDOL = T2.SEDOL
             OR T1.ISIN = T2.ISIN
```

Performance will be poor if the tables are large however, See [Is having an 'OR' in an INNER JOIN condition a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5901791/73226).

if both tables are consistent on the columns that are supplied for a particular security then this will potentially be much faster as it can use a hash or merge join not just nested loops.

```
SELECT *
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN T2
         ON EXISTS (SELECT T1.Ticker,
                           T1.SEDOL,
                           T1.ISIN
                    INTERSECT
                    SELECT T2.Ticker,
                           T2.SEDOL,
                           T2.ISIN)
```

Or if the tables are not consistent then another option might be

```
SELECT *
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN T2
         ON T1.Ticker = T2.Ticker
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN T2
         ON T1.SEDOL = T2.SEDOL
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   T1
       INNER JOIN T2
         ON T1.ISIN = T2.ISIN
```

Comment: This solution works but performs poorly as the two tables are both 20,000+ records.

Comment: Is there a way to only join on a field if it exists in both tables T1 and T2?  Would that speed things up?

Comment: Martin - thanks for your suggestion however the union and the intersect snippits above actually run slower than the first post (regular join).

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables? What do the execution plans look like? What join type are you getting for the `INTERSECT` query? If still nested loops maybe try `INNER HASH JOIN` and see if that improves things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISNULL key word in your ON part.

```
Select *
From tab1
inner join tab2 on tab1.ColName = Isnull(Isnull(tab2.Ticker,tab2.SEDOL),tab2.ISIN)
```

Added after a comment:
This query is done assuming you have a value in one column in one table, and in the other you have 3 columns where always 2 are null and one has a value that should match the column in the first table. The `ISNULL` is used to select the correct value from the 3 values.

Comment: SQL server has coalesce function which is basically isnull, but can take more than two parameters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but not sure how this would work... tab1.ColName is a specific column say ISIN.  It tab2.col1 is null and we use tab2.col2 (say SEDOL) it would never match right?

Comment: @user2584854 - added an explanation it the post itself

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from T1
    inner join T2 on T2.Ticker = coalesce(T1.Ticker, T1.SEDOL, T1.ISIN)
```

but if it possible that value in T1 is not null, but T2 doesn't have a corresponding value, you can do

```
select *
from T1
    outer apply
    (
        select top 1 T2.Col
        from T2
        where T2.Ticker in (T1.Ticker, T1.SEDOL, T1.ISIN)
        order by
             case
                 when T2.Ticker = T1.Ticker then 0
                 when T2.Ticker = T1.SEDOL then 1
                 when T2.Ticker = T1.ISIN then 2
             end
    )
```

or you can do

```
select *, coalesce(T21.Col, T22.Col, T23.Col) as T2_Col
from T1
    left outer join T21 on T21.Ticker = T1.Ticker
    left outer join T22 on T22.Ticker = T1.SEDOL
    left outer join T23 on T23.Ticker = T1.ISIN
```