# How to make JOIN with OR expression in DQL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is the SQL equivalent of what I expect to get from Doctrine:

```
SELECT c.* FROM comments c
  LEFT JOIN articles a
    ON a.id = c.articles_id OR a.translation = c.articles_id
WHERE c.published = 1 AND c.language = a.language
```

The problem is that I cannot make Doctrine to generate the `JOIN` operation with `OR` as it is supposed to be. If we execute query from the following `QueryBuilder` object:

```
$qb->select('c')
   ->from('Project:Comment', 'c')
   ->leftJoin('c.article', 'a', 'WITH', 'a = c.article OR a.translation = c.article')
   ->where('c.published = true AND c.language = a.language');
```

we receive the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM comments c0_ 
LEFT JOIN articles a0_ ON c0_.articles_id = a0_.id 
AND (
  a0_.id = c0_.articles_id OR
  a0_.translation = c0_.profiles_id
)
WHERE c0_.published = 1 AND c0_.language = a0_.language
```

which is obviously not the same as the initial query, as `WITH` operator seems to add additional conditions to the basic one instead of replacing the whole condition.

Is there any way to force Doctrine to output exactly what I need? I know that I may use native SQL but I doubt that it will be as convenient as `QueryBuilder`. Maybe there is a way to extend Doctrine with normal `JOIN ON` implementation instead of this odd `JOIN WITH`?

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine doesn't implement this because it is (as far as I understand at least) not considered optimized enough for SQL.

[See this SO post for precisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea).

What you intend to do could appearantly be done using `Union` and other types of `Join`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that neither `Join..OR` nor `Union` can be considered optimised enough to be implemented in Doctrine. Does that mean that there are no other options except native SQL?

Comment: @VisioN I do think so. In a general way, I think native SQL is more optimized 90% of the time, the only condition is that one's actually knows how to write proper optimized SQL (which is far from being my case).