# SQL Server - Inner Join On - Conditional Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I am using SQL Server 2008 and have the following scenario:

I have `Table a` with fields `id` and `groupId`.

I have `Table b` with fields `id` and `groupId` also.

The rule in `Table b`, is that:

```
If a.id = 0, then a.groupId = b.groupId
Else a.id = b.id (in which case a.groupId = 0)
```

The 2 tables are also linked by `agrId` such that `a.agrId` = `b.agrId`

How can I join these tables, whilst satisfying the rule above?

**Update**: Apologies for the lack  of clarity, I have updated the rule and added my attempt below:

```
select * from a
inner join b
on a.agrId = b.agrId
where (
    (b.id > '0' and b.groupId = '0') 
    or
    (b.groupId > '0' and b.id = '0')
  )
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Anyone of ID and GroupID will have the value... right?

Comment: You can join "conditional" using CASE etc, but if it is high performance you're after, specialized queries are better.

Comment: Join with what? ID = 0, join with GroupID, GroupID = 0, join with ID?

Comment: Keep in mind that using `OR` in `JOIN`s can hurt performance really bad. You'd better write them as equi-joins and do a `UNION`. Have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901791/is-having-an-or-in-an-inner-join-condition-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
    ON (B.ID = 0 AND A.groupId = B.groupId)
        OR (B.groupId = 0 AND A.id = B.id)
```

Comment: can u please edit anything in your answer .. i misunderstood the answer and downvoted but now its since more then 5 min i cannot rollback it

Answer (score 0):

Al it needs is an expression that evaluates to true or false, to indicate if these two rows should be joined. So based on what you say, this would be the join condition:

```
select  *
from    tA a 
        inner join tB b 
            on (a.id = 0 and a.groupid = b.groupid) 
            or (a.groupid = 0 and a.id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a INNER JOIN
       b ON a.agrId = b.agrId
WHERE  (b.id = '0' AND b.groupId = a.groupId) 
       or
       (b.groupId = '0' AND b.id = b.id)
```