# inner join performance issue with or condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, stored-functions

i have a sp which returns 3 millions records. right now its taking 16 minute . i am trying to optimize it. since there is a or condition in join its taking time. is there any way to optimize it?

```
SELECT
    id, from
FROM
    [#Temp1] AD              
    JOIN [#Temp2]  SS
        ON AD.Id = SS.Id
        OR (SS.Code = AD.Code AND AD.ID IS NULL)        
JOIN wTable1 WSS WITH(NOLOCK)               
    ON SS.PId= WSS.Id
```

Comment: That query, as it stands, won't even run. `from FROM`? Considering you're selecting from 2 temporary tables, however, then this suggests there are no indexes on either of these tables and hence why it's slow. Why not query directly against the original tables?

Comment: I think the first "from" in "from FROM" is a field name (?)

Comment: I suspect so, however, `FROM` is a reserved word in SQL Server, so it would need to be quoted for the above SQL to actually work.

Comment: Without knowing table structures, including indexes as well as approximate row counts for the persistent and temp tables this is guessing at best.

Comment: Is the `,` after `id` and before `from` on first line a mistake? And what take does that id refer to? It's not even qualified. Is that correct too?

Comment: Please post the execution plan of the query.

Comment: Also, what indexes do those tables have?

Comment: Also, please prepend the column names you are retrieving (`id` and `from`) with the table aliases. It's not clear to us where those columns are coming from.

Comment: On the off chance that SS.ID would be NULL anytime ad.ID is NULL, you could do On ISNULL(Ad.ID, AD.CODE) = ISNULL(ss.id = ss.code)

Comment: Can you please use SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON; SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;  We would need to see the whole plan and the table reads associated with this hotspot to understand exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Often the best approach is to use `left join`s:

```
select id, 
       coalesce(wss1.col, wss2.col) as col
from [#Temp1] AD left join            
     [#Temp2] SS1
     ON AD.Id = SS1.Id left join
     [#Temp2] SS2
     ON SS2.Code = AD.Code AND AD.ID IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     wTable1 WSS1            
     ON WSS1.Id = SS1.PID LEFT JOIN
     wTable1 WSS2
     ON WSS2.ID = SS2.PID
WHERE SS1.ID IS NOT NULL OR SS2.CODE IS NOT NULL;  -- one of the joins works
```

I cannot promise that this works in your specific case, because you have not provided sample data and desired results.  However, this approach does work in similar cases.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the likely duplicate [Is having an 'OR' in an INNER JOIN condition a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901901/73226) this will force a plan with nested loops and often replacing it with `UNION` pays dividends (`UNION ALL` in this case as the branches are mutually exclusive). In the below each branch of the `UNION ALL` can use hash or merge join as they are straightforward equi joins)

It is not clear what table each column comes from in your query but the basic approach is

```
WITH SS
     AS (SELECT SS.Id,
                SS.PId
         FROM   [#Temp1] AD
                JOIN [#Temp2] SS
                  ON AD.Id = SS.Id
         WHERE  AD.ID IS NOT NULL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SS.Id,
                SS.PId
         FROM   [#Temp1] AD
                JOIN [#Temp2] SS
                  ON AD.Code = SS.Code
         WHERE  AD.ID IS NULL)
SELECT SS.Id,
       WSS.[from]
FROM   SS
       JOIN wTable1 WSS 
         ON SS.PId = WSS.Id
```